# How to create modifiable dart array

Tags: dart

I want to create a buffer that can appended things.

For example

```dart
  var allInput = new Uint8List(1);
  allInput.add(list)
```

But it's informed me that this is can not be modify.

Comment: I'm curious why you're using Uint8List ? We might need to make it more clear that List is probably what most people want.

Answer (score 6):

Per the [API docs](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_scalarlist/Uint8List.html), Uint8List is a fixed list.  You could use code such as:

```dart
var allInput = new Uint8List(1);
allInput[0] = 123;
```

If you want a growable list, you could do something like:

```dart
var allInput = new List();
allInput.addAll(list);
```

or

```dart
var allInput = new List<int>();
allInput.addAll(list);
```

Essentially, if you provide a size specifier when creating a list, that makes it fixed size.  Otherwise it's extendable ([ref](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_core/List.html))

Comment: Thanks for that, indeed, I used Uint8List(1) for high performance and low memroy footprint.

Answer (score 2):

What Chris writes in his answer is correct today, but starting soon, the generic List constructor will not be fixed length when a length argument is given. The list’s size will still be changeable afterwards. There will also be a couple of additional named constructors for `List`:

```dart
factory List.fixedLength(int length, {E fill: null})
factory List.filled(int length, E fill)
```

these will help with constructing fixed length lists and creating lists with pre-filled values.

For details on bleeding edge changes to `List`, see:

http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_core/List.html